# Grouping into desired number of groups

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, grouping, data-manipulation

I have a data frame like this:
ID is the primary key and Apples is the number of apples that person has.

| ID | Apples |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | 10 |
| E2 | 5 |
| E3 | NA |
| E4 | 5 |
| E5 | 8 |
| E6 | 12 |
| E7 | NA |
| E8 | 4 |
| E9 | NA |
| E10 | 8 |

I want to group NA and non-NA values into only 2 separate groups and get the count of each. I tried the normal group_by(), but it does not give me desired output.

`Fruits %>% group_by(Apples) %>% summarize(n())`

```
Apples    n()
<dbl>    <int>
 4         1            
 5         2            
 8         2            
 10        1            
 12        1            
 NA        3
```

My desired output:

```
Apples    n()
<dbl>    <int>
 non-NA    7                    
 NA        3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a group for `NA` and non-NA using `group_by`, and we can also make it a factor so that we can change the labels in the same step. Then, get the number of observations for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = factor(is.na(Apples), labels=c("non-NA", "NA"))) %>% 
  summarise(`n()`= n())

#  grp     `n()`
#  <fct>  <int>
#1 non-NA     7
#2 NA         3
```

Or in base R, we could use `colSums`:

```
data.frame(Apples = c("non-NA", "NA"), n = c(colSums(!is.na(df))[2], colSums(is.na(df))[2]), row.names = NULL)
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", 
"E8", "E9", "E10"), Apples = c(10L, 5L, NA, 5L, 8L, 12L, NA, 
4L, NA, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer was helpful. I used dplyr with group_by(), so I can select more than 1 column in summarize(). Your base R answer is giving incorrect output- it's giving non-NA value count = 3, while actually it is 7.

Comment: @ella You're welcome! I just fixed the base R one; when putting it into the `data.frame` format, I didn't include `!is.na()`, but it is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, this can be done with `table` on a logical vector

```
table(!is.na(df1$Apples))
```